# Writing a script to automatically run against consecutive variables

Tags: command-line, scripts

So I'm trying to to convert one format of mac address to another, i.e.. from `XXXX:XXXX:XXXX` to `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`.

I was able to create a sed string using patterns but can only run it per mac address. Any suggestions on how to automate the script to run it against consecutive mac addresses?

Here's an example:

```
$ echo  5254.0040.8beb | sed  's/\.//g' |  sed -e 's/\([0-9A-Fa-f]\{2\}\)/\1:/g' -e 's/\(.*\):$/\1/'
52:54:00:40:8b:eb
```

I don't want to run it 100x:/

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us i) an example of your input and desired output and ii) the sed command you wrote. Normally, sed commands are applied to each line of the input file so it should already work as you describe. We can't help unless you give us the details.

Comment: Done...I'm very new so please have patience towards my ignorance....

Comment: Do you have these addresses stored in a file? If so, in what format (one per line, tab separated, ...) ?

Comment: per line as of now....I basically cp'd from the output of the switch port onto a  text file.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you added an example of your input file to your question as I asked in my previous comment. I think I've understood what you need but I can't be sure without the example. Try my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to save all your MAC addresses in a file, and then run the `sed` command on the file. Yours is needlessly complex though, try this instead:

```
$ echo 5254.0040.8beb | sed 's/\.//g; s/../&:/g; s/:$//'
52:54:00:40:8b:eb
```

The first `s///` removes the `.`, the second replaces every set of 2 characters (`..`) with themselves (`&`) and a `:`, and the third removes the `:` that the previous replacement added to the end of the line.

To run this on your file of MAC addresses (one address per line), do:

```
sed 's/\.//g; s/../&:/g; s/:$//' file
```

Comment: It WORKS!!!!!  Thanks a bunch...had to figure out a quick command to extract only the mac addresses from the switch output but once that was done the sed command worked like a champion!  THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 5254.0040.8beb | sed -r 's/\./:/g; s/([[:xdigit:]]{2})([[:xdigit:]]{2})/\1:\2/g'
52:54:00:40:8b:eb
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach with awk: in order to work with individual characters, define field separator as blank, get rid of the dot in the original MAC address, and  print dot after every second character. For a single MAC address the code will look like this:

```
echo 5254.0040.8beb  | awk -F '' '{gsub(/\./,"");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf $i;if(i%2 == 0 && i!=NF) printf ":"   }}'
```

We can turn the code into an executable script, like so:

1. create a file called `mac-editor.awk`. Its contents are in the file bellow
2. Make the script executable with `chmod 755 mac-editor.awk`;
3. Run the code with input file as an argument like so

   ./mac-editor.awk input-file.txt

**AWK script contents**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
FS="";
}

{
 gsub(/\./,"");
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
   printf $i;
   if(i%2 == 0 && i!=NF) 
      printf ":"   
 };
 printf "\n";
}
```

**Demo**:

The demonstration bellow shows how the script behaves with an input file where you have a list of MAC addresses, one per line.

```
$ cat mac-addresses.txt                                                        
7ab1.34b9.2eb0
2689.373c.d131
d271.a9a2.14c4

$ mac-editor.awk mac-addresses.txt                                             
7a:b1:34:b9:2e:b0
26:89:37:3c:d1:31
d2:71:a9:a2:14:c4
```